# Join regex expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these regex-es. The first one removes `brackets (), square [] brackets and the strings inside them` and the other removes `'` and `"`.

Note: They were not created by me.

How can I join them in a single regex?

```
str= str.replace(/(\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)) */g, '');
str= yt_title.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `|` alternation operator to combine the both regexes.

```
str.replace(/(\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)) *|['"]+/g, '');
```